# scala regex to match tab separated words from a string

Tags: regex, scala, match

I'm trying to match the following string

```
"name     type       this is a comment"
```

Name and type are definitely there.
Comment may or may not exist.
I'm trying to store this into variables n,t and c.

```
val nameTypeComment    = """^(\w+\s+){2}(?:[\w+\s*)*\(\,\,]+)"""
str match { case nameType(n, t, c) => print(n,t,c) }
```

This is what I have but doesn't seem to be working. Any help is appreciated.

```
val nameType    = """^(\w+)\s+([\w\)\(\,]+)""".r
```

However this works when i was trying to work with strings only with name and type and no comment which is a group of words which might or not be there.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an error message?

Comment: Try http://ideone.com/RwG7yl

Comment: Regex seem over complex for this. If they're really tab-separated, just `split` on `\t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `^(\w+\s+){2}(?:[\w+\s*)*\(\,\,]+)` regex only contains 1 capturing group (`(\w+\s+)`) while you define 3 in the `match` block.

The `^(\w+)\s+([\w\)\(\,]+)` only contains 2 capturing groups: `(\w+)` and `([\w\)\(\,]+)`.

To make your code work, you need to define 3 capturing groups. Also, it is not clear what the separators are, let me assume the first two fields are just 1 or more alphanumeric/underscore symbols separated by 1 or more whitespaces. The comment is anything after 2 first fields.

Then, use

```
val s = "name     type       this comment a comment"
val nameType    = """(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(.*)""".r
val res = s match { 
    case nameType(n, t, c) => print(n,t,c) 
    case _ => print("NONE")
}
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/RwG7yl)

Note that we need to compile a regex object, pay attention at the `.r` after the regex pattern `nameType`.

Note that a pattern inside `match` is *anchored* by default, the start of string anchor `^` can be omitted.

Also, it is a good idea to add `case _` to define the behavior when no match is found.

Comment: This worked. Thank you.
Could you explain what ([\w\)\(\,]+) means please?

Comment: You mean your pattern `([\w)(\,]+)` part? It matches 1 or more characters defined in the character class: either word chars  (letters/digits/underscore), `(`, `)`, or `,`.